# Is the product of two random variables finite if the expectation of the random variables squared is finite?

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, random

If $E X_t^2 < \infty$ and $E Y_t^2 < \infty$, then is $E X_t Y_t$ finite?

I am thinking yes, because of Cauchy-Schwartz, since $E X_t Y_t - E X_t E Y_t$ is an inner product, so it's less than something like $\sqrt{Var X_t } \sqrt{Var Y_t}$ which is finite?

But I am not sure.

Comment: You're right *a.s.*, but wrong deterministically.

Comment: Hm, how can it have anything to do with *a.s*? $E X_t Y_t$ is a real number, a constant, so if it is finite, it's finite, there's no *a.s* about it, since it's not a probablistic statement?

Comment: Sorry my bad.  I omitted the 'E' on the left.  $+1$ for nice use of C-S ineq.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Cauchy-Schwarz says $|\mathbb E[XY]| \le \sqrt{\mathbb E[X^2] \mathbb E[Y^2]}$.